# Login to website from app

Tags: c#

I would like to know more about how to login on a website from a windows form application

The site I am trying to login os z8games.com

I used RequestMaker from google chrome to get the post information. The idea is to fetch my clan members data automatically in order to have a nice picture of what is happening

Can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I tried getting an XML file from a website which required credentials I used the following:

```
 public static void GetFileWithCredentials(string userName, string password, string url)
{

    using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
    {
        wc.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password);
        string xml = wc.DownloadString(url);

        XmlDocument tournamentsXML = new XmlDocument();
        tournamentsXML.LoadXml(xml);
    }

}
```

Hopefully it is of some use for you. If it's not would it be possible to post an example of what the data you are trying to get looks like? I would've commented first but my reputation doesn't seem to allow me!